# is there a way to see a functions changes after that it were decorated?

Tags: python, decorator

for example for the below code is there any tool to see the definition of the function that is decorated?

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hello'
```

I tested `inspect.getsource(index)` but this only returns:

```
"@app.route('/')\ndef index():\n    return 'hello'\n"
```

Comment: Yes, you can look at the source code of the decorator to see which function it returns.

Comment: That depends on the decorator. It can keep the original intact, store it as an attribute or remove it completely. In case of `route()` the original remains as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to see what's the decorator `@app.route()` does, the answer lies in Python flask source code. I'm using flask 1.1.2 (the newest stable version currently is 2.0.0), and here is what it's defined in the file `app.py`, putting aside the many comments:

```
    def route(self, rule, **options):
        def decorator(f):
            endpoint = options.pop("endpoint", None)
            self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
            return f

        return decorator
```

Basically it complements the behavior of a route function (aka `rule` here) by adding it to the route processing infrastructure, and adds to this processing a generic object `f` -- probably a function -- to be used in the contexts of route processing.

The `Python flask` code is heavily commented, and it's very interesting to read it to get a finer idea of what `flask` does.

Comment: maybe because of my weak understanding of languages, I expect that there must be a way to see a dynamically declared function's definition from the REPL, I accept your answer.

Comment: Please don't say that, @kankan256 ! We're all learning here, and your question brought the mysteries of annotations to another light.